# Apply CSS Reset file to Next.js page

Tags: next.js

I know about this method of injecting CSS:

```
import Head from 'next/head'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <style jsx global>{`
            body {
              margin: 0;
            }
      `}</style>

      <Head>
        <title>audiom</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

But is there a way to quickly insert a css file (css reset in my case)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can import `reset.css` in [`_app.jsx` file](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app), it will apply css reset styles for all pages.

**_app.tsx**

```
import '../styles/reset.css';
```